# see a  in log file of go-ethereum, how does it do that? i always thought that we can only type charactor in linux file

Tags: vim, emoji, go-ethereum

i construct my private chain using go-ethereum, then i saw a  in log, it is amazing!, is it a new feature of vim?
i use Ubuntu 18.04.5 terminal in win10 to ssh into another desktop computer(also Ubuntu).
my vim version is 9.0

`INFO [09-28|08:27:29.517]  mined potential block                  number=1 hash=636909..62bf89`

Comment: it is just like your normal text, there are all [unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/) text.

Answer (score 0):

*is* [a character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F528) that Vim treats like any other character: it delegates the character's rendering to other components of your system that may or may not know what to do with the information. If the underlying system doesn't know, you get a � or some variant. If it knows, you get your hammer.